# Eclipse Oxygen: PHP: Content Assist & Syntax Highlighting Do Not Work in the RSE Perspective

Tags: php, eclipse

**Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2 ( for PHP )**

**Remote System Explorer plugin 3.5.0**

I'm using Eclipse and the RSE plugin on a RHEL box ( Linux )  to edit PHP files on a remote Linux ( RHEL ) server.

When I am editing those remote files I do not get Syntax Error highlighting nor Content Assit/code completion.

I get both of those features with Eclipse when editing PHP files on my hard drive.

I Googled on this issue and found a Stackoverflow post, but it was years old and the suggestions in it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this [blog post](http://wolfgang-langer.com/fixing-error-highlighting-and-autocomplete-in-eclipse-remote-system-explorer/).

1. Go to your Workspace>RemoteSystemsTempFiles directory
2. Bring up the .project file in an editor
3. Add these two lines at the bottom of the <natures>...</natures>section:

<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>

4. Restart Eclipse.